# Argument on why spin correlation functions in Ising model decay exponentially with a correlation length?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I'm reading *Quantum Field Theory in Strongly Correlated Electronic Systems, Nagaosa*.

Consider 1D Ising model,
$$H=J_z\sum_i S^z_iS^z_{i+1}.$$
on page 3, it says

> The groud stae is 2-fold degenerate because the Hamiltonian is invariant
> under the transformation $S^i_z \rightarrow -S^i_z$, performed at all sites $i$.
> Calling these two ground states $A$ and $B$ and assuming that the system at the right-hand side is in state $A$, and at the left-hand side in state $B$, then somewhere there
> must exist a boundary between region $A$ and region $B$. This boundary is called a kink or soliton. **Because at finite temperature this excitation occurs
> with a finite density, the spin correlation function $F(r) =\langle S^z_iS^z_{i+r}\rangle$ will decay exponentially with a correlation length $\xi$.**

I know how to directly calculate the correlation function, but I wonder how the argument for exponential decay of correlation function is made here and how to understand it.

Any help would be highly appriciated!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me write the Hamiltonian
$$
H = -J \sum_i S_i^z S_{i+1}^z.
$$
This choice will avoid some annoying (and irrelevant) signs.

One way to formulate the statement in the OP precisely is as follows.

Consider the variables $\delta_i=S_i^zS_{i+1}^z$. Since $\delta_i=1$ when the spins at $i$ and $i+1$ agree and $\delta_i=-1$ when the spins at $i$ and $i+1$ disagree, you can identify them with the kinks in your question (that is, there is a kink between $i$ and $i+1$ when $\delta_i=-1$).

Introducing the variables $\delta_i=S_i^zS_{i+1}^z$, the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
H = J^z \sum_i \delta_i.
$$
It follows that the random variables $\delta_i$ are independent and identically distributed. One can easily compute their expectation: since
$$
P(\delta_i = 1) = \frac{e^{\beta J^z}}{e^{\beta J^z} + e^{-\beta J^z}},
$$
one has
$$
\langle \delta_i \rangle = \frac{e^{\beta J^z} - e^{-\beta J^z}}{e^{\beta J^z} + e^{-\beta J^z}} = \tanh(\beta J^z).
$$
Finally, noting that $S_i^zS_{i+r}^z = \delta_i\delta_{i+1}\cdots\delta_{i+r-1}$, we obtain
$$
\langle{S_i^zS_{i+r}^z}\rangle = \langle\delta_i\delta_{i+1}\cdots\delta_{i+r-1}\rangle = \langle \delta_i \rangle^r = (\tanh(\beta J^z))^r.
$$

---

In words, the fact that kinks proliferate in the system (at each $i$, there is a positive probability that a kink is present, so there will be a positive density of them in the system) prevents the ordering of the spins.

Comment: Thanks! What you post is what I considered "directly calculate the correlation function", but I wonder would it be fair to say that in systems that can have finite excitation density (a gapped system?), some "correlation function" will decay exponentially with a correlation length?

Comment: The 1d Ising model being so simple, once you formulate the problem precisely, you can usually just compute everything explicitly... But the qualitative answer is the one I give at the end: the probability of having an interval of length L in which all spins are equal decays exponentially since between each pair of neighbors, you have a positive probability of having a kink.

Comment: Why must it decay "exponentially" then?

Comment: For the same reason that the probability that you obtain n heads in a row when flipping a coin decays exponentially with n...

Comment: Another explanation : start with the spin at the left end of the interval. Each time you encounter a kink, the spin changes sign. So, the spin at the right end will have the same sign as the spin at the left end if and only if you have an even number of kinks. But the probability of this happening converges to 1/2 exponentially fast with the length of the interval.

Comment: Concerning your question above *"would it be fair to say that in systems that can have finite excitation density [...] some "correlation function" will decay exponentially?"*. You always have a positive density of excitations (except, classically, at T=0). It's really a combination of this *and* very specific properties of one-dimensional systems. For instance, in the 2d Ising model, each spin has a positive probability of being equal to -1 in the + phase, so you'll have a positive density of such excitations, but they will not be enough to prevent long-range order at low enough temperatures.

Comment: In this sense, I find the vague statement in the book rather misleading (and would just ignore it), since it does not apply in higher dimensions and they do not seem to discuss (at least in the piece you extracted) the very special properties of one-dimensional systems that make it relevant there. It *is* of course possible to combine the observation that there is a positive density of excitations with the fact that the system is one-dimensional to derive a general claim that 1d classical systems with short-range interactions always have a finite correlation length, but this is not "obvious".

Comment: Does this clarify your issue?

Comment: Thank you and sorry i just saw your reply!! One more question, would you please futher explain "For the same reason that the probability that you obtain n heads in a row when flipping a coin decays exponentially with n..." for me? This doesn't look so obvious to me...

Comment: It is what I tried to explain above. Since $\langle S_0^z S_r^z \rangle = 2{\rm Prob}(S_0^z=S_r^z)-1$, we can just compute the latter probability. For the 2 spins to coincide, you need to have an even number of changes of sign in the interval $\{0,\dots,r\}$. But, since change of signs happen independently between each pair of neighbor, this probability converges exponentially fast to $1/2$ (it's just a little combinatorial computation).

Comment: Alternatively, and closer to the analogy with a coin, you can express correlations in the Ising model in terms of a percolation model : $\langle S_0^z S_r^z \rangle$ is then equal to the probability that all edges between $0$ and $r$ are open. But each edge has a positive probability of being closed (similarly as a coin having a positive probability of showing tail), so the probability that all are open is exponentially small in $r$.

Comment: You can learn more about this representation as a percolation model in Section 3.10.6 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). (This is the representation on which are based the cluster algorithms for the simulation of the Ising model: Swendsen-Wang, Wolff, etc).